# Erro Laravel: [ReflectionException] Class App\Units\Commands\Inspire does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Estou recebendo esse erro:

**Codigo consoleKernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Units;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel;
use App\Console\Commands\EnvioEmailBlCron;

class ConsoleKernel extends Kernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\Inspire::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\EnvioEmailBICron::class 
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        //configuração do cron
        $schedule->command('inspire')->dailyAt('01:00'); 
        $schedule->command('envioemailbicron:cron')->daily(); // email diários
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o namespace da classe `Inspire`?

Comment: Não encontrei nada declarado na classe em questão..

Comment: onde encontro essa classe?

Comment: caso Inspire não esteja instalado como proceder ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe `Inspire` só serve de exemplo para disponibilizar comandos de testes.

Remova-a do array `$commands`

```
protected $commands = [    
    \App\Console\Commands\EnvioEmailBICron::class 
];
```